# Illegal Argument Exception for setDate in java

Tags: java, java-time, localdate, date

I have the following code which converts the Java `LocalDate` to a particular format while passing as a parameter for `setDate`.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy");
String formattedString = localDate.format(formatter);
storedProcedureCall.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(formattedString));
```

But it always throws an `IllegalArgumentException` when I include `formattedString` in the argument for `setDate` but works fine when I do:

```
storedProcedureCall.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(java.time.LocalDate.now()));
```

In general:

```
storedProcedureCall.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(java.time.LocalDate.now())); // working

storedProcedureCall.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(formattedString)); // not working
```

Comment: From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)): "Throws:
`IllegalArgumentException` - if the date given is not in the JDBC date escape format (yyyy-[m]m-[d]d)"

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any research.  Please [edit] your question to include the research you have done and *precisely* where you are having difficulty.  If you can do this, I may retract my downvote.

Comment: If you need to save the current date, just use `java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now())`. The `setDate` method takes a `Date` as parameter, and date objects [**have no format**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date). If you want to *show* this value later, in another format, then you use the `DateTimeFormatter`'s `format` method to convert the `Date` to a `String`.

Comment: I believe your `storedProcedureCall` has a `setObject` method that accepts a `LocalDate` directly so you don’t need to go through the outdated `java.sql.Date` class. Please try `storedProcedureCall.setObject(2, java.time.LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()));`. It requires a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver, but I believe those are commonplace now. The `ZoneId.systemDefault()` isn’t strictly necessary, but recommended to make it explicit that today’s date is time zone dependent and that you have made a conscious choice of time zone.

Comment: Ya i have tried that but am getting invalid column type exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy");
String formattedString = localDate.format(formatter);
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.from(LocalDate.parse(formattedString, formatter).atStartOfDay());
storedProcedureCall.setDate(1, Date.from(ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
```

This should work. But if you work with standard library that use `java.util.Date` but not new classes like `LocalDate`, it is more comfortable to use `old` java classes.

As I understand, your goal is to set current date to `storedProcedureCall`. In Java any date is a `long`. Do not worry about local and other features, until you convert it to String. So you could solve your problem with only one line:

```
storedProcedureCall.setDate(1, new java.util.Date());
```

**P.S.** How to convert `24 oct 2017` to `Date` instance and set it to `storedProcedureCall`:

```
storedProcedureCall.setDate(1, new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.US).parse("24 oct 2017"));
```

Comment: ya the goal is to set the current date to storedProcedureCall but in the format ("dd MMM yyyy"). Format is the main goal otherwise this is easily working with java.sql.Date.valueOf(java.time.LocalDate.now())

Comment: Then you have error in your example, because `java.sql.Date.valueOf()` produce a `Date` instahnce, not a `String`. You could talk about date format only when you use `String`, not a `Date`. If table column has `Date` format, then you just set `Date` isntance, and it does not depend on any string date format.

Comment: So how can i convert my formattedString(24 oct 2017) string type to Date type in storedProcedureCall.setDate(3,java.sql.Date.valueOf(formattedString));

Answer (score -1):

Use this format

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Your Code should be like that:

```
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String formattedString = localDate.format(formatter);
    storedProcedureCall.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(formattedString));
```

Comment: I need my date in the format ("dd MMM yyyy"). currently am using the same code that you have mentioned except the format.

Comment: Date string to be parsed should be in this format"yyyy-MM-dd". Why you need this format?

Comment: To save the format change setdate stored procedure to take string instead of date or format your date in stored procedure